# Using Texture as label in WhirlyGlobe

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, textures

[WhirlyGlobe](http://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/) is a very useful framework and I would like to display Country Flags instead of names for each countries.
When looking at LabelLayer.h it seems possible to overwrite the icontexture generated from Text label by a picture:

```
@interface SingleLabel : NSObject  {      
NSString *text;      
WhirlyGlobe::GeoCoord loc;      
NSDictionary *desc;  // If set, this overrides the top level description
WhirlyGlobe::SimpleIdentity iconTexture;  // If non-zero, this is the texture to use as an icon  }
```

But I didn't find any way to use label for picture display.
Can someone please help me understand how to replace Text label by Picture label?

Following @Mousebird first answer here is what I"ve implemented:

```
// This describes how our labels will look
    NSDictionary *labelDesc = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"enable",
     [UIColor clearColor],@"backgroundColor",
     [UIColor whiteColor],@"textColor",
     [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0],@"font",
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],@"drawOffset",
     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.08],@"height",
     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.08],@"width",
     nil];

    // Build up an individual label
    NSMutableArray *labels = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    SingleLabel *texLabel = [[[SingleLabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    Texture *theTex = new Texture(@"icon", @"png");
    theTex->setUsesMipmaps(true);
    texLabel.text = @"";
    texLabel.iconTexture = theTex->getId();
    theScene->addChangeRequest(new AddTextureReq(theTex));
    [texLabel setLoc:GeoCoord::CoordFromDegrees(5, -3)];
    [labels addObject:texLabel];
    [self.labelLayer addLabels:labels desc:labelDesc];
```

Still a problem, the texture is loaded in memory but didn't appear. Putting a string as a text create a Blank square on the first character of the label

Comment: Is icon.png a power of 2 along each side?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.  I need to set up some sort of feed for stackoverflow.

Anyway, the short answer is there isn't a great way to do it.  I'm adding Markers for a client, but that won't be out until 1.2.  For now, you should be able to make a label display a texture.  That's the iconTexture you're showing there.

To create a texture, do the following:

```
Texture *theTex = new Texture(@"nameoftexture", @"png");  
theTex->setUsesMipmaps(true);  
theTexId = theTex->getId();  
scene->addChangeRequest(new AddTextureReq(theTex));
```

And then to use it:

```
singleLabel.text = @"";  
singleLabel.iconTexture = theTexId;
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you took time to answer.
I've implemented your code, but still no Textures in the label. my updated code in the first question.

Comment: Add in some text to make it easier to find.  Could just be a size issue.